# Difference Between SPSS Modeler and SPSS Statistics?

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

I guess we can perform most of the operations of modeling in SPSS Statistics software itself, so why there is need of two software packages doing the same thing?

If I am wrong please correct my doubts and help me decide when to use what

Comment: SPSS Statistics (formerly SPSS) is a general purpose statistical package. SPSS Modeler (formerly Clementine) is a data mining package. Knowing that you can deduce differences.